# Uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation

Tags: c, malloc, hashtable, valgrind

I'm trying to implement a dictionary of words using a hash table, so I need to have it global, and in one of my header files I declare it

```
extern node** dictionary;
```

Where node is

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Then in another file in which functions are defined I include the header which has the dictionary declaration, and also I add at the top

```
node** dictionary;
```

Then in the function which actually loads the dictionary I first allocate memory for the linked lists which will make the hash table

```
bool load(const char* dict_file)
{
    dictionary = malloc(sizeof(node*) * LISTS);

    FILE* dict = fopen(dict_file, "r");

    if(dict == NULL)
        return false;

    char buffer[MAX_LEN + 2];

    size_dict = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN + 2, dict) != NULL)
    {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

        int len = strlen(buffer);

        new_node->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len));

        //avoid \n
        for(int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
            new_node->word[i] = buffer[i];

        new_node->word[len - 1] = '\0';

        new_node->next = NULL;

        int index = hash(buffer);

        new_node->next = dictionary[index];

        dictionary[index] = new_node;

        size_dict++;
    }

    if (ferror(dict))
    {
        fclose(dict);
        return false;
    }

    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}
```

So the program works fine, I then free all the allocated memory for strings and nodes and when I run valgrind(a debugger which detects memory leaks) it says no memory leaks are possible, but it says that there is an error *Uninitilised value was created by a heap allocation* and redirects me to that exact line where I'm allocating memory for `dictionary` the exact first line of the load function which I've written above.
What am I doing wrong? I guess the way I use `dictionary` globally is wrong, so can anybody suggest some other way of keeping it global and avoid this error?

Comment: The code that you have shown does not reproduce the error, so it's probably due to something else that you've not shown us.

Comment: But I did so only because it sends me to this line only, the following code is just a file reading, word by word, creation of a node for each word, and selection of each node in the appropriate linked list(26 of them, where the node goes depends upon the first letter of the word it rapresents)

Comment: The problem is in the rest of the code, any particular reason why you don't post it? I am trying to help you, but the rest of the code is required.

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimal example that shows the problem . [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to do this.

Comment: do you see the code??

Comment: I assume you are trying to implement a hash-table? What is `LISTS`? And shouldn't the dictionary be initialized as an array of linked-lists:
`node *dictionary[LENGTH]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the updated code you use an uninitialized pointer:

```
dictionary = malloc(sizeof(node*) * LISTS);

// .... code that does not change dictionary[i] for any i

new_node->next = dictionary[index];   // use uninitialized pointer
```

As people had wrote already, this will only work if you had pre-set all the pointers to be `NULL` before entering this loop:

```
dictionary = malloc(sizeof(node*) * LISTS);
if ( !dictionary ) {
    return false;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < LISTS; ++i) {
    dictionary[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: NB. Your line `new_node->next = NULL;` is redundant as you then go on to overwrite that straight after.

Comment: yes I know, it should have been for each node* in dictionary instead, otherwise the last node points to some garbage value intead of being NULL, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The heap allocation you assign to `dictionary` uses `malloc` which does not initialize the returned bytes.  So `dictionary` in the code you've posted ends up being an array of uninitialized pointers.  Presumably you go on to use those pointers in some way which valgrind knows to be an error.

An easy way to fix this is to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, because it zeros the returned bytes for you.  Or, use `memset` to zero the bytes yourself.

Comment: Where I've written //code... In the load function I actually skipped 60 lines of code, where I load word by word from a file, create a new node for each word and make the node* to which <code>dictionary</code> is pointing, a pointer to such nodes, and all the other node* for which I allocated memory are actually used

Comment: Indeed my program runs correctly, the words rapresents by nodes are correctly distributed in the array of node* 's and then freed

Comment: Using `calloc` hides the fact that you don't initialize something somewhere, unless you want to explicitly initialize to `0` using `calloc`, it is hiding another problem.

Comment: I think this answer makes a good point... Are all nodes initialized? Does the last node point to null?

Comment: @Grantly but it is suggesting a bad practice, isn't it?

Comment: Bad practice yes, but his point of focusing on the initialization is a good idea.... If calloc fixes or stops the error, then he can remove calloc after fixing the init problem and move on.  If calloc does not fix it .... Then there is a different issue,... It's a quick test ....

Comment: This "answer" is merely a guess as to what valgrind is complaining about ... and it is almost certainly wrong. P.S. Zeroing pointers with calloc or memset is undefined behavior.

Comment: All nodes are initialized, I'm loading 100k+ words, and all the 100k+ Nodes are distributed in 26 linked lists, where a node goes is determined by its fist letter, we have A to Z letter, and 26 lists, so they are all initialized!

Comment: @Core_dumped please just post the rest of the code.

Comment: @Jim Balter Certainly "Zeroing pointers with calloc or memset"  is _not_ undefined behavior.  What code does with those "zeroed" pointers later has the undefined behavior potential.

Comment: @chux Silly and misleading quibbling when you are well aware of the point that all-zero bits is not guaranteed to be NULL, and the claim that "An easy way to fix this is to use calloc instead of malloc" is wrong; that doesn't fix anything (aside from the fact that this answer is a misdiagnosis).

Comment: @JimBalter looks like correct diagnosis to me (although non-portable suggested solution as you point out)